# How I can fix 'failed to parse the `edition` key' in anchor build command?

Tags: rust, anchor-solana

I am trying run anchor build but

```
error: failed to download `anchor-attribute-access-control v0.26.0`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/Users/???/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anchor-attribute-access-control-0.26.0/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  failed to parse the `edition` key

Caused by:
  this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
```

I fix `edition` but I see the same error for another packages. (for example)

```
Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/Users/???/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anchor-attribute-account-0.26.0/Cargo.toml`
```

I guess I can do smth I don't need fix manually each package.

Thanks

PS:
rustup -V:

```
rustup 1.25.1 (bb60b1e89 2022-07-12)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.66.1 (90743e729 2023-01-10)`
```

cargo -V

```
cargo 1.66.1 (ad779e08b 2023-01-10)
```

anchor -V

```
anchor-cli 0.26.0
```

os: macOS Big Sur 11.6.5

Comment: you should consider posting this question in the solana subdomain of stackoverflow